# Multiple first_visit events associated with the same user_pseudo_id in GA4 BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I have a user_pseudo_id from GA4 data pulled from Big Query (BQ). However I have found an example that has x2 first_visit event associated with it. I find that strange as I thought this event was unique to the user_pseudo_id. This means I also have multiple session number 1's occurring on different days. Can anyone explain why this is?

*Image below shows my export from BQ. custom_session_id, hit_number, and et_timestamp are all custom columns.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have multiple first_visit events associated with the same user_pseudo_id in GA4 BigQuery. This might be due to the first_visit event being not unique to the user_pseudo_id. Instead, it is unique to the combination of user_pseudo_id and app_instance_id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I don't see the app_instance_id column within the GA4 schema (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846). I tried looking in the app_info record, but all values for the user_pseudo_id in my question were null as the both sessions were on a desktop device

Comment: What was also weird was that I looked up the same user_pseudo_id again, and the data had changed. Now just the first session (5/15 20:51) was associated with that user. I also found 20 or so other instances of this occurring. When using a data range in my intraday tables, I found that these were all concentrated around the start and end of my dates. This could well just be a coincidence. Hard to say with Google being a blackbox and all...

Comment: And lastly, I get completely different results when I query my events tables vs my intraday tables. In both sets of data (and over a two week period), I have about 50 user_pseudo_id's with multiple first_visit events. But the none of the user_pseudo_id's are the same in each dataset. I am not setting any Custom User ID, but I do have Google Signals turned on. Perhaps it's something to do with how the device graph is working on the backend??