# first_visit event in BigQuery GA4 during the navigation

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76291557/multiple-first-visit-events-associated-with-the-same-user-pseudo-id-in-ga4-bigqu). I think it is similar but not the same.

When I analyze some user sessions in BigQuery I discover that a same client_id (user_pseudo_id) initiates a session with first_visit event then session counter is set to 1 and the user is considered as new but the previous days the user exists and the behaviour is the same (as far as i can see).

For example:

[User inits new session ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cazqK.png)

The session_starts come frome google.com navigation, so, a new session starts a the time 13:39 after the last event as 12:21.

But the same day, for the same user this happens.

[Now the first_visit event is launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV4BJ.png)

The behaviour is the same, after the last event at 13:45, new session is started a 16:15 but this time with first*visit.* Same clientId, same device, same browser.

Te issue is that I think I am getting new users when they are not.

I have tried to see if in the website sometimes in the call to analytics sends the parameter _fv that determines the first_vist.

I also tried to see if in GTM GA4 configuration tag is some strange.

The same issue is happening with more users.

user_id is configured in GTM tag.